# Gestures setting on LG G3 running Android Marshmallow

Tags: settings, 6.0-marshmallow, lg-g3

I have LG G3, now running on Android Marshmallow. Prior to Marshmallow, I had this setting under **Settings - Gestures**. Now, I can't find it on Marshmallow.

Did LG remove it? If not, where is it?

Answer (score 1):

The features are still there, LG only moved the settings to other place.

From [a post by jtrvk on XDA Forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=64641112&postcount=1310),

> The gesture settings regarding calls have been moved to main phone
>     **Settings - Call** - scroll down to Gesture
>
> For smart screen gesture, that setting is now listed under **Display**

Comment: Sorry, but "gestures" doesn't appear in either of those places, at least on my phone. I have checked every single setting, and no "gestures".

Comment: I see.. Sorry, I'm not sure if I can help you further since I don't have the device. Hopefully someone else can solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Just found the answer to the "...by putting the phone to your ear" setting on my LG G3. It wasn't in the general settings. I opened the phone icon on the home screen and then opened the menu in the right hand corner → Call Settings.  The options for answering the phone with the gestures were there.